# Use foreground service to communicate with network

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

I have an desktop application that receives data via websocket (server) and an android client websocket sending data (PC input can be controlled via android). Both also do the other job (sending/receiving) but pretty rarely. I want the client to run as a foreground service, so I can send data like clipboard from android and receive e.g. music (artist, etc.) from server.

My question: how can I build a foreground service that holds the websocket open while also maintaining fast (20 requests per second) communication with the activity, including callback? I used a Singleton (Kotlin object) before but with the foreground service that sounds even worse than with the activity open. I don't seek a coded solution here, just a plan on how i can pull this off.

Thanks in advance and sry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use Bound service - the Activity binds to the service as described here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services